# How to select part of a text in R

Tags: r, text-mining

I have an HTML file which consists of 5 different articles and I would like to extract each one of these articles separately in R and run some analysis per article. Each article starts with `< doc>` and ends with `< /doc>` and also has a document number.Example:

```
<doc>
<docno> NA123455-0001 </docno>
<docid> 1 </docid>
<p>
NASA one-year astronaut Scott Kelly speaks after coming home to Houston on  
March 3, 2016. Behind Kelly, 
from left to right: U.S. Second Lady Jill Biden; Kelly's identical in      
brother, Mark; 
John Holdren, Assistant to the President for Science and ...
</p>
</doc>
<doc>
<docno> KA25637-1215 </docno>
<docid> 65 </docid>
<date>
<p>
February 1, 2014, Sunday 
</p>
</date>
<section>
<p>
WASHINGTON -- Former Republican presidential nominee Mitt Romney 
is charging into the increasingly divisive 2016 GOP 
White House sweepstakes Thursday with a harsh takedown of front-runner 
Donald Trump, calling him a "phony" and exhorting fellow 
</p>
</type>
</doc>
<doc>
<docno> JN1234567-1225 </docno>
<docid> 67 </docid>
<date>
<p>
March 5, 2003
</p>
</date>
<section>
<p>
SEOUL—New U.S.-led efforts to cut funding for North Korea's nuclearweapons
program through targeted 
sanctions risk faltering because of Pyongyang's willingness to divert all
available resources to its 
military, even at the risk of economic collapse ...
</p>
</doc>
```

I have uploaded the url by using `readLines()` function and combined all lines together by using

```
 articles<- paste(articles, collapse=" ")
```

I would like to select first article which is between `< doc>..< /doc>` and assign it to `article1`, and second one to `article2` and so on.

Could you please advise how to construct the function in order to select each one of these articles separately?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should edit with the actual text instead of an image of it so other people can work with it. You can separate it by indenting it all by at least four spaces to mark it as code.

Comment: You will get the most help if you can make this reproducible.  Can you provide the `readLines()` call you used including the url?

Comment: You probably want to use a function that accepts XPath. The *XML* package has a few.  That's all I can give you without a reproducible example.  The answer by alistaire also shows a method.  Regex should not be used on html, IMO.

Comment: @cdeterman and Richard Scriven, thank you for your comments and apologies that i couldn't share the URL. It is a private piece of article and i am not authorized to share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `strsplit`, which splits strings on whatever text or regex you give it. It will give you a list with one item for each part of the string between the splitting string, which you can then subset into different variables, if you like. (You could use other regex functions, as well, if you prefer.)

```
splitArticles <- strsplit(articles, '<doc>')
```

You'll still need to chop out the `</doc>` tags (plus a lot of other cruft, if you just want the text), but it's a start.

A more typical way to do the same thing would be to use a package for html scraping/parsing. Using the `rvest` package, you'd need something like

```
library(rvest)
read_html(articles) %>% html_nodes('doc') %>% html_text()
```

which will give you a character vector of the contents of `<doc>` tags. It may take more cleaning, especially if there are whitespace characters that you need to clean. Picking your selector carefully for `html_nodes` may help you avoid some of this; it looks like if you used `p` instead of `doc`, you're more likely to just get the text.

Comment: Hi @Alistaire, thanks for helping. Indeed strstring() works fine, however i couldn't understand why level [1] has only quotation mark. You can see the result which i got below. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?
[[1]] 
[1] ""
[2] " <docno> NA123455-0001 </docno>
<docid> 1 </docid><p>...article 1..</doc>
[3] " <docno>..article 2...<doc>"
[4] "<docno>..article 3...<doc>"

Comment: It's splitting on the `<doc>` at the beginning, and since there's nothing before it, it splits into an empty string and the rest. You can correct for this one case by either subsetting it out or changing the regex to specify that you don't want a `<doc>` at the beginning of the string: `[^^]<doc>`. ([Here's a tutorial to see what's going on with the regex.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)) 

Really, I recommend using `rvest` or another scraping/parsing package, though; it lets you cut through the HTML more intelligently and will more reliably get you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is use `strsplit`:

```
art_list <- strsplit(s, "<doc>")
art_list <- art_list[art_list != ""]
ids <- gsub(".*<docid>|</docid>.*", "", art_list[[i]]  )
ids <- ids[ids != ""]
for (i in 1: length(unlist(art_list)) ){
assign( paste("article",  ids[i], sep = "_") ,  gsub(".*<doc>|</doc>.*", "", unlist(art_list)  )[i] )}
```